# In the canvas I loose the cursor

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens

I'm working since 2 months with HoloLens and unity3d. I'm currently working on an application where I'm using a menu (composed of a canvas & a panel). However, when I want to select something in the menu, the cursor (default cursor from Holotoolkit) dissapears automatically. I know that there are options like change the button's color where I'm selecting it but personally I find better the cursor. What I should do in order to see always the cursor independent of the surface.

Comment: post your codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Also double check what layer your canvas and panel are in. Sometimes they get put into the IgnoreRayCast Layer. You can change this to the UI layer and it will work fine.

Try using a different cursor from the HoloToolKit a few of them tend to be a little buggy when dealing with UI. During runtime try and replicate the bug and then go into your scene view and see if you can find the cursor or see if it is just not rendering.

Also not sure if this will help or not but make sure in your EventSystem add the component HoloLens Input Module, most people don't know to do this.

Here are some guidelines from Unity on using UI and the HoloLens

https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-ui-on-the-hololens.394629/

Answer (score 0):

maybe i misunderstood your question , but if the problem is in Unity Editor, Make sure in Player settings default Cursor is set to None. 
* i didn't have enough reputation to leave comment.